# Selenium Webdriver TimeoutException Error start at WebDriverWait line

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

**I want to auto get my content in numbers page but first it need to be login first, and here is my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import random

# def scrapp():
# List of driver classes
drivers = [webdriver.Firefox, webdriver.Chrome, webdriver.Edge]

# Shuffle the list to choose a driver randomly
random.shuffle(drivers)

# Try to initialize a driver
for driver_class in drivers:
    try:
        driver = driver_class()
        break
    except Exception:
        continue
else:
    raise Exception("No suitable driver found")

# Go to the login page
driver.get('https://www.orangecarrier.com/login')

# Find the email and password fields
email_field = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='email')
password_field = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='password')

# Type your email and password into the fields
email_field.send_keys('xxx@yopmail.com')
password_field.send_keys('xxxx')

# Submit the form
driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="loginSubmit").click()
driver.get('https://www.orangecarrier.com/numbers')

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'select')))

# Find the select tag
select = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='MyNumbers_length'))
select.select_by_value('500')

WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'td')))
page_cont = driver.page_source

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_cont, "html.parser")
print(html_soup)
driver.close()
```

**and after over 10 times run, it just work about 3~4 times, even i have to close my computer then tried in another day, it might just work, or not, it been a few days.
This is my error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\...\tesst.ipynb Cell 3 line 4
     39 driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="loginSubmit").click()
     40 driver.get('https://www.orangecarrier.com/numbers')
---> 42 WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'select')))
     44 # Find the select tag
     45 select = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='MyNumbers_length'))

File c:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:95, in WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)
     93     if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     94         break
---> 95 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6DBB08EF2+54786]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DBA75612]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DB92A64B]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DB96B79C]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DB96B91C]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DB9A6D87]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DB98BEAF]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DB9A4D02]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DB98BC43]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DB960941]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DB961B84]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6DBE57F52+3524194]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6DBEAD800+3874576]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6DBEA5D7F+3843215]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6DBBA5086+694166]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DBA80A88]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DBA7CA94]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DBA7CBC2]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF6DBA6CC83]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF8A43257D+29]
RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF8C10AA78+40]
```

I modified a lot from may kind of wait options, set timeout longer but it will load like foreverr...and it's not worked.

Comment: Could you provide html code just before WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'select')))? Looks like your element is not visible sometimes, thats why you get TimeoutException

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try to add a delay between submitting your login information and getting on another page. It can be made static (like 2-3-5 seconds) or you can wait with `WebDriverWait()` until your credentials are accepted and the after-login page is loaded properly. (For some reason it was helpful before on some sites)